# Maven build error on win 32 os

Tags: android

I'm trying to build an source code with ndk on maven,but it failed to build the source code.It shows below error log on windows OS-32.I don't understood what I making wrong here. I'm new to use maven to build an application.Any help.

```
> [INFO] Error installing artifact's metadata: Error installing
> metadata: Error up dating group repository metadata
> 
> expected START_TAG or END_TAG not TEXT (position: TEXT seen
> ...<extension>pom</. .. @13:25) [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Trace org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException:
> Error installing artifac t's metadata: Error installing metadata:
> Error updating group repository metadat a
>         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(Defa
> ultLifecycleExecutor.java:583)
>         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLi
> fecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:499)
>         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(Defau
> ltLifecycleExecutor.java:478)
>         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHan
> dleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:330)
>         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegmen
> ts(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:291)
>         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLi
> fecycleExecutor.java:142)
>         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:336)
>         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:129)
>         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:287)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
> java:39)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
> sorImpl.java:25)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>         at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
>         at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
>         at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
> 
>         at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375) Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error
> installing arti fact's metadata: Error installing metadata: Error
> updating group repository meta data
>         at org.apache.maven.plugin.install.InstallMojo.execute(InstallMojo.java:
> 143)
>         at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPlugi
> nManager.java:451)
>         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(Defa
> ultLifecycleExecutor.java:558)
>         ... 16 more Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.installer.ArtifactInstallationException: Er
> ror installing artifact's metadata: Error installing metadata: Error
> updating gr oup repository metadata
>         at org.apache.maven.artifact.installer.DefaultArtifactInstaller.install(
> DefaultArtifactInstaller.java:91)
>         at org.apache.maven.plugin.install.InstallMojo.execute(InstallMojo.java:
> 92)
>         ... 18 more Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.metadata.RepositoryMetadataInsta
> llationException: Error installing metadata: Error updating group
> repository met adata
>         at org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.metadata.DefaultRepositoryMetada
> taManager.install(DefaultRepositoryMetadataManager.java:463)
>         at org.apache.maven.artifact.installer.DefaultArtifactInstaller.install(
> DefaultArtifactInstaller.java:79)
>         ... 19 more Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.metadata.RepositoryMetadataStore
> Exception: Error updating group repository metadata
>         at org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.metadata.AbstractRepositoryMetad
> ata.storeInLocalRepository(AbstractRepositoryMetadata.java:76)
>         at org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.metadata.DefaultRepositoryMetada
> taManager.install(DefaultRepositoryMetadataManager.java:459)
>         ... 20 more Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException: expected ST
> ART_TAG or END_TAG not TEXT (position: TEXT seen
> ...<extension>pom</... @13:25)
> 
>         at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.nextTag(MXParser.java:1083
> )
>         at org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.metadata.io.xpp3.MetadataXpp3Rea
> der.parseVersioning(MetadataXpp3Reader.java:513)
>         at org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.metadata.io.xpp3.MetadataXpp3Rea
> der.parseMetadata(MetadataXpp3Reader.java:352)
>         at org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.metadata.io.xpp3.MetadataXpp3Rea
> der.read(MetadataXpp3Reader.java:866)
>         at org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.metadata.AbstractRepositoryMetad
> ata.updateRepositoryMetadata(AbstractRepositoryMetadata.java:98)
>         at org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.metadata.AbstractRepositoryMetad
> ata.storeInLocalRepository(AbstractRepositoryMetadata.java:68)
>         ... 21 more [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 3 seconds [INFO] Finished at: Thu Jun 28 19:21:01
> IST 2012 [INFO] Final Memory: 13M/32M [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: `expected START_TAG or END_TAG not TEXT ...`, make sure your pom.xml is valid and well-formed.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your currently installed artifact from your local repository.